# Creating function to get means based on column levels

Tags: r, permutation

I'm trying to create a function that gives me the means based on another column's levels. I know that R has plenty of functions that do this same thing, but since I'm planning to use the boot package, as I could see I need to provide a function to be used (this package appears not to have pre defined functions such as "FUN=mean"). Sorry for such a basic question!

I searched on pages about the basics of function creation in R but couldn't find what I want. Here an example what I want using iris dataset and tapply:

```
data(iris)
with(iris, tapply(Sepal.Length, Species, mean))
```

So, I want a function that gives me the means (Sepal.Length) of each level (Species) of a X data.table (in this case, iris).

```
setosa versicolor  virginica 
 5.006    5.936      6.588
```

Comment: You have code that delivers what you want. So the intent of your question is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to bootstrap means by groups, you can do something following the lines below.

This is your code, the means by group of `Species`, full dataset.

```
res1 <- with(iris, tapply(Sepal.Length, Species, mean))
```

Now a bootstrap function and its application.

```
library(boot)

bootMeans <- function(data, indices, val, catg, na.rm = FALSE){
  val <- deparse(substitute(val))
  catg <- deparse(substitute(catg))
  d <- data[indices, ]
  tapply(d[[val]], d[[catg]], mean, na.rm = na.rm)
}

set.seed(1234)
b <- boot(iris, bootMeans, R = 1000,
          val = Sepal.Length, catg = Species, na.rm = TRUE)

identical(b$t0, res1)
#[1] TRUE

colMeans(b$t)
#[1] 5.006788 5.940504 6.588357
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a wrapper function around `tapply` and use that, setting `FUN` to `mean`. Something like:

```
func <- function(data, x, y) {
  tapply(data[[x]], data[[y]], mean) 
}
```

And then you use it like:

```
func(iris, 'Sepal.Length', 'Species')
#    setosa versicolor  virginica 
#     5.006      5.936      6.588
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option with `tidyverse`

```
f1 <- function(data, grpCol, valueCol) {
        grpCol <- enquo(grpCol)
        valueCol <- enquo(valueCol)
        data %>%
            group_by(!! grpCol) %>%
            summarise(Mean = mean(!! valueCol))
 }

f1(iris, Species, Sepal.Length)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Species     Mean
#  <fct>      <dbl>
#1 setosa      5.01
#2 versicolor  5.94
#3 virginica   6.59
```